# Unable to download unsampled report from Google Analytics using Java

Tags: java, google-analytics

We have created unsampled report using Google console and the report got generated under Google Drive. Now to automate the downloading process, we are trying to download the report using Java.
As per Google Analytics API library, it can be done by using Report's `selfLink()` method. We are able to print the link using this method but unable to download the report. There is no error but download process is failing. 
How can we fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [selflink](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports#selfLink) property for the unsampled report resource, is the self link for that particular resource. To actually download the results of an unsampled report, you need to go set up either a [cloud storage API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/overview) request or a [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) request depending on your implementation.

For example if your unsampled report is stored in Google Drive, you make an authorized HTTP GET request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. For example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/XXXXXX?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

where XXXXXXX is the unsampled report [driveDownloadDetails.documentId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports#driveDownloadDetails.documentId).