# Google Analytics unsampled report : How to set a destination location (Google Drive OR GCS)?

Tags: python, google-analytics

## Getting Unsampled Report from GA Management API

I need to programmatically download google analytics unsampled reports and ultimately store them into BigQuery daily.

My first step is actually being able to download an unsampled report.

Navigating through the GA management API v3, I'm able to get metadata for a given report with python:

```
{
    "id": "ONJ5uJntQ5Ku4U5vZ6z5tQ",
    "kind": "analytics#unsampledReport",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/XXXX/webproperties/UA-XXXX/profiles/XXXX/unsampledReports/ONJ5uJntQ5Ku4U5vZ6z5tQ",
    "title": "MCF Export 20201124 20201124",
    "accountId": "XXXX",
    "webPropertyId": "UA-XXXX",
    "profileId": "XXXX",
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "created": "2020-11-25T21:22:35.308Z",
    "updated": "2020-11-25T21:24:13.695Z"
}
```

As mentioned in this related post: [Unable to download unsampled report from Google Analytics using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917223/unable-to-download-unsampled-report-from-google-analytics-using-java?rq=1)

The selflink attribute is the actual link of the resource but not a download endpoint.

To DL the report, one needs to query the GDrive OR GCS API.

My problem is: How to tell where the report has to go?

As for now, when querying report data, there is no location URI, I still receive a partial answer like this guy: [Why is Google Analytics API for Unsampled Reports not showing Google Drive Download Link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056687/why-is-google-analytics-api-for-unsampled-reports-not-showing-google-drive-downl)

Here is the official google analytics management API documentation: [https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/unsampledReports/get](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/unsampled-reports)

From the following code :

```
 analytics.management().unsampledReports().get(
            accountId=ACCOUNT_ID,
            webPropertyId=WEB_PROPERTY_ID,
            profileId=PROFILE_ID,
            unsampledReportId='XXXX'
        ).execute()
```

I should get:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "kind": "analytics#unsampledReport",
  "selfLink": string,
  "title": string,
  "accountId": string,
  "webPropertyId": string,
  "profileId": string,
  "start-date": string,
  "end-date": string,
  "metrics": string,
  "dimensions": string,
  "filters": string,
  "segment": string,
  "status": string,
  "downloadType": string,
  "driveDownloadDetails": {
    "documentId": string
  },
  "cloudStorageDownloadDetails": {
    "bucketId": string,
    "objectId": string
  },
  "created": datetime,
  "updated": datetime
}
```

Still, my answer is lacking any download information...

I would be extremely grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in `driveDownloadDetails.documentId`, so you have to use Google Drive API to get this file by its ID.

I made an add-on with Google Apps Script to export Google Analytics Unsampled data in Spreadsheet, calle '**[GA360 Unsampled](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/ga360_unsampled/990419743199?hl=en)**' and in my case, for example, I got the reference to the file through that information (then manage blob, parseCSV, etc...):

```
...
fileId = driveDownloadDetails.documentId;
...

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
```

Obviously you will have to use syntax of the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks, Michele, for your help,

In my case, the attribute ```driveDownloadDetails.documentId``` is not part of the answer I get when calling the following code : 

```analytics.management().unsampledReports().get(
            accountId=ACCOUNT_ID,
            webPropertyId=WEB_PROPERTY_ID,
            profileId=PROFILE_ID,
            unsampledReportId='XXXX'
        ).execute()```

Comment: OK, issue fixed.

I was trying to get information for a report created from the analytics web UI.
It seems only report creating from the GA management API get a driveDownloadDetails.documentId !

Comment: Yes, great!. :)